# Unity3d php image upload

Tags: c#, php, html, unity-game-engine

I have an HTML script and a PHP script to upload images on my raspberry pi server and it works. I have an app I built in unity3d for taking pictures at work and I can access my gallery in my app with the native android gallery which is free. How do I upload the image as an image file to the php post from unity? Is there a way without having to datachunck it?

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the php upload code that works.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$target_dir = "";
$target_file = base64_encode($target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["theFile"])) {
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
 if($check !== false) {
   $uploadOk = 1;
 } else {
   echo "File is not an image.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
 }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
 echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
 $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000) {
 echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
 $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
 echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
 $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
 echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
   echo "Copy the link below and add to Website Address or Picture Menu Address: \r\n"."adatouch.hopto.org/". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
 } else {
   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have writing permission on the server folder. I ended up `chmod 777` it which I guess is not good but it fixed the issue.